# How to handle multiple object IDs in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Do you have guidance on how we handle multiple object IDs from the same user (user comes in from Facebook and Google, two object IDs, same email populated in email fields)? 
a.  Tell them too bad – treat it as separate accounts.
b.  Build a process in our apps to reassign data to different user objects.
c.  Build a process in our apps to link multiple user objects to the same data.

Comment: Which identity providers will you be adding? A local account (email or username) as well as social accounts? Or only social accounts?

Comment: Both social and local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution for this is to create [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom) that link a local account with a social account.

This is demonstrated by [the Wingtip Games site](https://wingtipgamesb2c.azurewebsites.net/).

(You are free to experiment with this sample site.)

The basic flow is this:

1. An end user signs up for a local (i.e. Wingtip) account. The custom policy creates a user object and saves the verified e-mail address for the end user in the "signInNames" property of the user object.
2. The end user clicks a "Link your social account" button in the Wingtip Games site.
3. The end user signs in with the local account (if they haven't already done so) that was registered in step 1. The custom policy retrieves the user object that was created in step 1. The end user then signs in with a social (e.g. Facebook) account. The custom policy saves the the social account identifier for the end user in the "alternativeSecurityIds" property of the user object.
4. The end user can then sign in with either the local account or the social account and manage a single profile.

The current limitation for this flow is that a single local account can only be linked with a single social account.

The application code for the Wingtip Games site can be found at [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/wingtipgamesb2c/src).

The custom policies for this site can be found at [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/wingtipgamesb2c/Policies).